# Why doesn't stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: convert L%C3%A9on back to Léon?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have the following:

```
modifiedTitle = @"Léon";
modifiedTitle = [modifiedTitle stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedTitle);
```

Converted, it now shows as `L%C3%A9on`.

When I run the following it doesn't convert it back:

```
NSMutableString *searchText = [NSMutableString stringWithString:modifiedTitle];
[searchText stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", searchText);
```

It still shows as `L%C3%A9on`.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` returns a new string. Try this:

```
NSMutableString *searchText = [NSMutableString stringWithString:modifiedTitle];
NSString *newText = [searchText stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", newText);
```